# How to enable simple Flask application logging in deployed Elastic Beanstalk site?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, python-logging

I have a simple "hello world" Flask application deployed into AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Before I start building my application I want to ensure everything is working, including simple application logging. I followed [this AWS article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html) on setting it up, but I can't get my log from EB (and so I don't know whether it got created and logged messages or not either).

Here is the Flask code in my app, which shows in the output console when running locally and creates the expected log file in /tmp/application.log on my local macOS system. But "eb logs" as well as GUI download of logs doesn't contain my /tmp/application.log. What am I doing wrong?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import logging
from logging import FileHandler
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

# EB looks for an 'application' callable by default.
application = Flask(__name__)

#  routes
@application.route('/')
def index():
    print("Hello from print")
    application.logger.info("Hello from logger")
    return render_template('index.html')

# run the app (this has to go last otherwise the routes above are not registered yet)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    # file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('tmp/application.log', maxBytes=1024,backupCount=5)
    file_handler = FileHandler('/tmp/application.log')
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    application.logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
    application.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    application.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    application.run(use_debugger=True, use_reloader=False, passthrough_errors=True)
```

Here is my .ebextensions/logging.config file:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/taillogs.d/application.conf" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      /tmp/application.log
      
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/bundlelogs.d/application.conf" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      /tmp/application.log
```